# AWS Service:ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com conditions keys not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-sts

I am trying to create assume role policy for an IAM role which will be assumed by ECS TASK. I want to put a condition that only ECS Container with specific Arn should be able to assume role.
Here is my policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
          "StringLike": {
               "ecs:cluster": "ECS cluster Arn"
          }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above policy is not working and even not letting the ECS Cluster mentioned above to assume the role. So, is there any other way we can do this? Any help would be appreciated.